# Why is this parallelized code spending the same amount of time as a non-parallelized code?

Tags: performance, math, rust, parallel-processing

I'm still relatively new to coding in Rust and picked up a college project to parallelize the Newton-Raphson method to a system of non-linear equations to see performance improvements. After reading Rust's official book Chapter 16 - Fearless Concurrency, I gave it a try. But as soon as I tried to run the code, I noticed that it took the same amount of time to display the results* in the terminal. My questions are:

1. Why is it running as slow as non-parallelized code?
2. What did I do wrong to make it run as slowly as non-parallelized code?
3. What can I do to really see some performance gains?
   (*: the results produced are completely off scale - they start with some wild values like 2e31 and scale down to 0.5 for example)
   Here is the code:

teste.rs

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

pub fn derivada_parcial(funcao: impl Fn(&[f32]) -> f32, indice: usize) -> impl Fn(&[f32]) -> f32 {
    let h: f32 = 0.001;
    move |x: &[f32]| {
        let mut x_mais_h = x.to_vec();
        let mut x_menos_h = x.to_vec();
        x_mais_h[indice] += h;
        x_menos_h[indice] -= h;
        (funcao(&x_mais_h) - funcao(&x_menos_h)) / (2.0 * h)
    }
}

pub fn par_elim_gauss_og(tam: usize, a: &mut [Vec<f32>], b: &mut [f32]) -> Vec<f32> {
    // Pivoteamento
    for i in 0..tam {
        let mut max_linha = i;
        for j in (i + 1)..tam {
            if a[j][i].abs() > a[max_linha][i].abs() {
                max_linha = j;
            }
        }
        if max_linha != i {
            a.swap(i, max_linha);
            b.swap(i, max_linha);
        }
    }

    // Paralelização?
    let atom_a = Arc::new(Mutex::new(a.to_vec()));
    let atom_b = Arc::new(Mutex::new(b.to_vec()));
    let mut handles = vec![];
    let total_threads = 24;

    // Resolução
    for num_thread in 0..total_threads {
        let atom_a = Arc::clone(&atom_a);
        let atom_b = Arc::clone(&atom_b);
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut a_cop = atom_a.lock().unwrap();
            let mut b_cop = atom_b.lock().unwrap();
            let inicio = (num_thread * tam) / total_threads;
            let fim = ((num_thread + 1) * tam) / total_threads;
            for i in inicio..fim {
                for j in (i + 1)..tam {
                    let m = a_cop[j][i] / a_cop[i][i];
                    for k in i..tam {
                        a_cop[j][k] -= m * a_cop[i][k];
                    }
                    b_cop[j] -= m * b_cop[i];
                }
            }
        });
        handles.push(handle);
    }

    for handle in handles {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }
    // Substituição
    let mut x: Vec<f32> = vec![0.0; tam];
    for i in (0..tam).rev() {
        let mut soma = 0.0;
        for j in (i + 1)..tam {
            soma += a[i][j] * x[j];
        }
        x[i] = (b[i] - soma) / a[i][i];
    }
    x
}
```

main.rs

```
use rand::Rng;

use crate::teste::{derivada_parcial, par_elim_gauss_og};

mod teste;

fn main() {
    const TAM: usize = 1000;
    let a: &mut[Vec<f32>] = &mut vec![vec![0.0; TAM]; TAM];
    let x_0: &[f32] = &[1.0; TAM];
    let b: &mut [f32] = &mut [0.0; TAM];

    for i in 0..TAM {
        for j in 0..TAM {
            // Variáveis aleatórias que acompanharão as variáveis x_i
            let potencia: f32 = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1.0..=6.0);
            let constante: f32 = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1.0..=10.0);
            let aleatorio_i: i32 = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0..=1);

            // Criação das funções e suas derivadas em i
            let funcao = |x: &[f32]| (-1.0_f32).powi(aleatorio_i) * constante * x[j].powf(potencia);
            let derivada = derivada_parcial(funcao, j);

            // Preenchimento do vetor A e vetor B (de Ax = B)
            let valor = derivada(x_0);
            a[i][j] += valor;
            b[i] += funcao(x_0) * (-1.0);
        }
    }

    let resultados = par_elim_gauss(TAM, a, b);
    println!("Resultado: {:#?}", resultados);
}
```

Side note: in main.rs I am populating the jacobian matrix with some random constants appended to each variable (I am trying to simulate a system of n non-linear functions with n variables). Variable names and comments are in Brazilian Portuguese.

I expected the "parallelized" code to run faster, but, there was no performance gain in it. The book states that when using Arc and Mutex the priority is thread safety and not performance; but to see no performance gains when running the code in multiple threads seems off. I think one of the problems might be that I'm not running different chunks of code in different threads? I really don't know.

Answer (score 2):

> What did I do wrong to make it run as slowly as non-parallelized code?

```rust
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut a_cop = atom_a.lock().unwrap();
            let mut b_cop = atom_b.lock().unwrap();
```

You share the `a` and `b` vectors between all the threads, and the first thing each thread does is take a lock on the vectors, which it does not release until  it finishes. Therefore, there can be at most one thread doing work at a time, since one thread holds the locks and the other threads are all waiting for the same locks.

> What can I do to really see some performance gains?

You need to, first, change your algorithm to one that *can* be parallelized. Your algorithm seems to be both reading and writing different parts of `a`, but not in a way that is sliceable; you will have to structure your code so that at least the writes *are* in different slices of the vector.

Then, divide your vector into chunks and give each chunk to a different thread. Here is a simple example of doing that:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut data: Vec<usize> = vec![0; 100];

    let chunk_size = 10;
    let chunk_iter = data.chunks_mut(chunk_size).enumerate();
    std::thread::scope(|s| {
        for (i, chunk) in chunk_iter {
            s.spawn(move || {
                // chunk is a &mut [u32]
                for (j, d) in chunk.iter_mut().enumerate() {
                    *d = i * 100 + j;
                }
            });
        }
    });

    println!("{data:?}");
}
```

Notice that there are **no locks**, so no thread ever waits for another — this is a key element of getting high parallelism, because every microsecond spent waiting for a lock to be available is a microsecond where you're not doing any useful computation. You also don't need to use `Arc`, because these are scoped threads which can borrow data; `Arc` is mostly needed for *non*-scoped threads which need to own all the data they use.

In this example, `i` is the thread number and `j` is the index within the chunk. You could compute the index in the vector as a whole (if this is needed for your algorithm) as `i * chunk_size + j`.

Note that from within each thread, you **cannot** read from elements in the vector outside of the chunk. This is because the other threads have **exclusive** access to their own chunks; this is a key part of how Rust provides **safe** concurrency.

If you need to read data while also writing, you may wish to use a “double buffering” strategy: make two copies of the data (two vectors), read from one and write to the other, then when appropriate, swap the roles of the two vectors so that you're reading from the newer one and writing to the older one.

That may or may not be the best option; as you write, you have a “project to parallelize the Newton-Raphson method”, and that means **you** will have to figure out what algorithm to use (whether it is novel or found in the literature), within the constraints of Rust's memory and concurrency model.

---

I also strongly recommend that you try out the [`rayon`](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/) library. It provides “parallel iterators” that automatically execute on multiple threads. It is intelligent in that it automatically splits the work into as many parts as suits the available cores, and the parallel iteration API often makes problems easy to express. However, it does have some overhead; if you know *exactly* what you're doing, you may be able to beat it by planning your own threads since you know the exact shape of the problem.